# React component AMD bundling with Webpack for Require.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, backbone.js, require

Due to some reason, we want to load React component on Backbone view (with Require.js). This React component is being bundled using Webpack 4.x.

We have enable AMD/UMD mode during bundling in Webpack config.

```
...
...
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    componentName: ['./components/componentName/index.js']
  },
  amd: {
    componentName: true
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './componentName'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'componentName',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },

  externals: {
    'react': 'react',
    'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    'react-dom-server': 'react-dom-server'
  },
  ...
```

Now, we are trying to use bundled React component in Backbone+Require.js app where we are loading React and ReactDOM (UMD enabled) as below

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'react',
  'react-dom',
  'componentName'
], function($, _, Backbone, React, ReactDOM, componentName) {

   ...

   render: function() {
      console.log(React, ReactDOM, componentName)
   }

   ...
});
```

Here componentName always comes as `undefined` whereas React and ReactDOM are loading correctly. Can anyone help to understand am I missing something here?